# How to plot this type figure in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

please tell me, How to plot this type figure (see, [image]attached file) in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is generally appreciated, if people show at least some ideas, some code of what they have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with stacks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,stackengine}
\def\rdar#1{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{#1}{$\Rightarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}\ensurestackMath{
\frac{f}{g} ~
\stackanchor[1.5\baselineskip]{\rdar{30}}{\rdar{-30}} ~
\stackanchor[2.5\baselineskip]{\dfrac{h}{H}}{\dfrac{G}{z}} ~
\stackanchor[1.5\baselineskip]{\rdar{-30}}{\rdar{30}} ~
F(z)
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this an an alternative.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,stackengine}
\def\rdar#1{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{#1}{$\Rightarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}\ensurestackMath{
\frac{f}{g} ~
\stackanchor[1.5\baselineskip]{\rdar{30}}{\rdar{-30}} ~
\stackanchor[2.1\baselineskip]{h/H}{G/z} ~
\stackanchor[1.5\baselineskip]{\rdar{-30}}{\rdar{30}} ~
F(z)
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tikz-cd` for this.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,row sep={.5cm,between origins}
    ,every arrow/.append style=Rightarrow
    ]
& \dfrac{h}{H} \drar & \\
\dfrac{f}{g} \drar\urar & & F(z) \\
& \dfrac{G}{Z} \urar
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=\baselineskip and 1cm]
   \node (start) {$\frac{f}{g}$};
   \node[above right=of start] (mid-high) {$\frac{h}{H}$};
   \node[below right=of start] (mid-low) {$\frac{G}{Z}$};
   \node[below right=of mid-high] (end) {$F(Z)$};

   \foreach \s/\e in {start/mid-high,start/mid-low,mid-low/end,mid-high/end}  {
       \path (\s) --node[sloped] {$\Rightarrow$} (\e);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```